# Missing Symbols after resuming windows in Xamarin.forms app

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, standby

I have a Multiplattform app in Xamarin.forms for iOS, Android and UWP.
I'm using materialdesignicons-webfont.ttf for all my symbols.
If the windows goes in standby mode and resume after that, all symbols are missing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SymbolTest"
             x:Class="SymbolTest.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <OnPlatform x:Key="MaterialFontFamily" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/Fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.ttf#Material Design Icons" />
            </OnPlatform>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <StackLayout>

        <Label Text="&#xf844;"  HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
            <Label.FontFamily>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                    <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/Fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.ttf#Material Design Icons" />
                </OnPlatform>
            </Label.FontFamily>
        </Label>

        <Button Grid.Column="1" x:Name="btnSearch" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" >
            <Button.ImageSource>
                <FontImageSource FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialFontFamily}"  Size="36" Glyph="&#xf349;" Color="SlateGray" />
            </Button.ImageSource>
        </Button>


    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

The ButtonImage ist missing the Label.Text is not missing

Comment: Have you recently updated your project? In `4.5.0.142-pre1` there are changes to embedded fonts

Comment: I've tried 4.5.0.142-pre1. In this Version the Symbols are missing from the beginning.

Comment: Could you share a sample that could reproduce the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

> Missing Symbols after resuming windows in Xamarin.forms app

I created code sample follow this [tutorial](https://dev.materialdesignicons.com/getting-started/xamarin), And it works well if I sleep the computer and resuming, please check the following code if you have missed some key procedure.

```
<Label Text="&#xf844;">
    <Label.FontFamily>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String"> 
            <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/Fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.ttf#Material Design Icons" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </Label.FontFamily>
</Label>
```

[image]

**Update**

I could reproduce your issue, and it only occurs in reference `StaticResource` scenario, it looks a bug, please feel free post the bug report in Xamarin github, and I will report it to related team.

Comment: I added a Sample. The Button Image is missing after resume.

Comment: @KlausGrosche I could preproduce this issue , and it looks a bug. I will report it

Comment: I've reported this at [GitHub](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9277)